# How can I make the bottom row overlap with the top row like what is shown in the picture?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[Desired Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0SUx.png) [Current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iua2Q.png) I've been trying to play around with Rows and Columns but it's not giving me the desired layout. I'm stumped with how to make the bottom row overlap with the top. I'm using a ListView.builder to generate these containers dynamically. This is my code for the ListView.builder:

```
ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: moduleCount,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        /*
                        Makes graphicModule decrease in size as more
                        modules are being displayed
                         */
                        if (moduleCount > 6) {
                          containerWidth = 112.5;
                        } else {
                          containerWidth = 150;
                        }

                        if (index.isEven) {
                          return Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              makeGraphicModule(
                                  index + 1, containerWidth, moduleCount),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 50,
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 50,
                              ),
                              makeGraphicModule(
                                  index + 1, containerWidth, moduleCount),
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use margin top for the odd containers

```
ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: moduleCount,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if (moduleCount > 6) {containerWidth = 112.5;} 
            else {containerWidth = 150;}
          return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: index.isEven ? 0 : 50),
              child: makeGraphicModule(
                    index + 1, containerWidth, moduleCount),
                    );,
          }
      ),
```